# Most Efficient way to compare large 'text' type values in MySQL using InnoDB

Tags: mysql-5.6, performance, blob, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a staging table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `staging` (
  `created_here_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `desc_text`  TEXT NOT NULL );
```

And destination table as :

```
  CREATE TABLE `final_tbl` (
      `row_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `created_here_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `desc_text`  TEXT NOT NULL );
```

I want to insert desc_text into final_tbl only if it is not present. I am thinking of two options :

1. check if staging.desc_text exists in final_tbl.desc_text, if not
   then insert into final_tbl
2. Maintain a column in 'final_tbl'
   that will store the SHA224 value of desc_text column. compare SHA224
   value of staging.desc_text with SHA224 column in final table and
   then decide whether to insert or ignore.

I want to know which option will be faster?

Comment: Create a large amount of dummy data & benchmark it. Anything else is pure speculation